# eth0 Disconnected on Kali Linux ARM

Tags: networking, kali-linux, raspberry-pi, arm

I have recently installed Kali Linux ARM on a flash drive for my Rasberry pi. Upon boot up, I ran into the `device not managed` problem. If you do not know what this is, it is where by default Linux does not manage Ethernet connections.

You can read the article I used as my solution here:

> [How to fix Wired Network interface `"Device not managed"` error in Debian or Kali Linux? | BlackMore Ops](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/11/25/how-to-fix-wired-network-interface-device-not-managed-error/)

I went through all the steps of the article, however when I enter   `service network-manager restart` I do not get any prompts from the terminal as the article does. It just completes the command.

Now, my Ethernet reads `disconnected` when on the physical layer it is certainly connected. If you want proof that all the steps in the article are completed, my /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file currently is this:

```
[main] 
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile 

[ifupdown] 
managed=true
```

I assume there are some discrepancies between normal Linux and ARM Linux causing this problem. However currently I cannot connect to the Internet with my RasPi, are there any solutions to it simply reading `disconnected`?

Comment: The joy of NetworkManager.  I have been known to nuke it from high orbit and manually set up the interface and just use the network service.  BUT, this makes moving from one network to another painful.  Maybe someone who knows how to actually make NM work will chime in.

Comment: @Xalorous r/linuxquestions has so far suggested I just use wicd and nuke NetworkManager all together. This seems like the best option thus far. It would be nice to find a solution however.

Comment: I don't know wicd, but I'm in a server environment, and our configs are static.  It irritates me that so much has been shifted to NetworkManager on Servers.  Servers are typically static on network config.  NetworkManager, with all of its bells and whistles, seems to serve the mobile segment more.  NetworkManager suits when changing from network to network as you go from home to school/work and then whatever hangout.  Of course Kali is pentesting environment, so manually setting the network settings should be within the operator's skillset.

Comment: What is the output of `service network-manager status`?

Comment: @JigglyNaga network-manager: unrecognized service

Comment: Is `network-manager` even installed? (`dpkg -l network-manager`)  Did you run the `service network-manager ...` commands as root?

Comment: @JigglyNaga I dunno, I've moved over to Rasbian now, and the issue persists even after configuring for DHCP. It's odd, as the physical layer is good. Since it's Rasbian, I will be making a new question for this. This no longer involves NetworkManager nor Kali Linux.

Answer (score 1):

First, open the Network Manager configuration file in /etc/NetworkManager with a text editor, and set "managed=false". Then edit network configuration file `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
# The loopback network interface 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then reboot your computer.
Check that Ethernet cable is good and auto negotiation is enabled via command `ethtool eth0`.

Answer (score 0):

Go old school.  Google up how to set network settings without NetworkManager.  In RHEL based distro's I know it's done through the config files `/etc/sysconfig/network` and `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifg-eth0` (where eth0 is your interface).  Edit those, then `service network restart` and you should be back in business.  Word of advice, turn off the interface (`ifdown eth0`) before editing it, since the same config is used to turn off the interface.  You can get them stuck if you don't down one before editing the file.